# Function Not returning results on Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I wrote this function below:

```
leg.rpps = function(es, municipio) {
    est = as.character(es)
    mun = as.character(municipio)
    url = paste0("https://apicadprev.economia.gov.br/RPPS_REGIME_PREVIDENCIARIO?sg_uf=", 
                     est, "&no_ente=", curlEscape(mun), "&")
    tmp = tempfile()
    hdl = curl::new_handle(ssl_verifypeer = 0)
    curl::curl_download(url, destfile = tmp, handle = hdl)
    tpdt = fromJSON(tmp)
    dt1 = (tpdt$results)
    dt2 = dt1$data
    dt.real = dt2[[1]]
    rm(tpdt, tmp, dt1, dt2)
    dados = cbind(dt.real$sg_uf, dt.real$no_ente, dt.real$no_tipo_legislacao, 
                      dt.real$nr_legislacao, dt.real$dt_legislacao, dt.real$te_ementa)
        colnames(dados) = c("UF", "Ente", "Tipo Legal", "No. Dispositivo", 
                            "Data Publicação", "Ementa")
        return(datatable(dados))
}
```

it works fine by itself, generating the expected results. But when I try to build a shiny app and call it , I get no results at all. The shiny page just stays blank where the data table was supposed to appear. Below is the code for my app (I must say that I'm a beginner on shiny, so I might be f'in up some shiny-related code)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(curl)
library(jsonlite)
library(RCurl)

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Legislação RPPS por Ente"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(inputId = "estado",
                label = "Estado - Sigla:",
                value = ""),
      textInput(inputId = "municipio",
                label = "Município:",
                value = ""),
      actionButton(
        inputId = "click_go", 
        label = "Ir")
),
    mainPanel(
      h1("Legislação RPPS"),
      h4("Utilizar sigla do Estado (Em maiúscula) e Nome do Município com as 
         iniciais em Maiúscula"),
      dataTableOutput("tabela")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  leg.rpps = function(es, municipio){
    url = paste0("https://apicadprev.economia.gov.br/RPPS_REGIME_PREVIDENCIARIO?sg_uf=", 
                 es, "&no_ente=", curlEscape(municipio), "&")
    tmp = tempfile()
    hdl = curl::new_handle(ssl_verifypeer = 0)
    curl::curl_download(url, destfile = tmp, handle = hdl)
    tpdt = fromJSON(tmp)
    dt1 = (tpdt$results)
    dt2 = dt1$data
    dt.real = dt2[[1]]
    rm(tpdt, tmp, dt1, dt2)
    dados = cbind(dt.real$sg_uf, dt.real$no_ente, dt.real$no_tipo_legislacao, 
                  dt.real$nr_legislacao, dt.real$dt_legislacao, dt.real$te_ementa)
    #colnames(dados) = c("UF", "Ente", "Tipo Legal", "No. Dispositivo", 
     #                   "Data Publicação", "Ementa")
    #return(datatable(dados))
    datatable(dados)
  }
  current_data = eventReactive(
    input$click_go,
    leg.rpps(input$estado, input$municipio)
  )
  
  output$tabela <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$click_go)
    current_data()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm having a really hard-time to figure out what might be wrong with this. If anyone can even point me out a way out of this, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Could you provide an example input for the values `es` and `municipio` so I can see what the datatable is supposed to look like?

Comment: `es` should be the abbreviation of a brazilian state name, like "SP" (for São Paulo) and `municipio` is the name of a city of that state, like "São Paulo" (which is the capital of São Paulo state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, I was calling a datatable on another datatable.

when I changed `datatable(dados)` to `dados` on `leg.rpps()` outcome, it worked.